# Things to Take Care While Upgrading from EF5 to EF6

Tags: entity-framework

Recently i upgraded from EF5 to EF6 and here is list of items which one needs to take care of

1. **EF MiniProfiling**: if you were using mini profiling with EF5 you will have broken code as few of the functiionality or variable names had been changed.
   **Resolution:** Upgrade to newer version of EF MiniProfiling
2. **Db-Reindexing**: After updating to EF6 it complaints you about change in your model and when you do "Add-Migration" you will see all your index for primary key were getting recreated also its changing name of tables where you have one to one relationship so previously if it generates table name as TableATableB then it will rename table as TableBTableA dont know why.
   **Resolution 1**: Let EF create migrations for create index , just comment out line in
   up and down function.
   **Resolution 2**: Copy line of code from down function(i.e. drop index) and try to execute it before it create index , simple rule first drop and then create, you need this else EF will complaint about index already present.
3. **Migrations**: This will only affect you if you are doing using some tool to deploy you assemblies and which in turns uses migrate.exe typically found at
   ...#your project location\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.0\tools\migrate.exe
   copy it to your bin folder and things should work fine.

4. **Null Handling**: In EF6 handling of null values had been changed , my hands on experience says that with ef5 select query was ignoring null cases but is not the case with ef6
e.g. if i have query something like

```
 db.context.entity.where(name != "ab");

 and lets say entity table contains two names {"ab",null}

 with EF5 it will return 1 row with ef6 it was returning 2 rows  

 http://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/2115
```

**Resolution**: If you wanted to work exactly like EF5 you can set
    dbContext.Configuration.UseDatabaseNullSemantics = true;

If it helps please don't forgot to mark this post as answered :)

Comment: Was this intended to be an answer to a question?

Comment: Yes,its more like info.